# Qt Webkit Bridge: Call C++ functions with javascript

Tags: javascript, c++, qt

Hello I made a HTML5 Application with QtCreator using QT5.

My main.cpp looks like the following:

```
#include <QApplication>
#include "html5applicationviewer.h"

#include "sqlfunctions.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    sqlfunctions* obj = new sqlfunctions;

    QApplication app(argc, argv);

    Html5ApplicationViewer viewer;
    viewer.setOrientation(Html5ApplicationViewer::ScreenOrientationAuto);
    viewer.showExpanded();
    viewer.loadFile(QLatin1String("src/index.html"));
    viewer.setFixedSize(1200, 900);

    return app.exec();
}
```

What i want to achieve is calling a C++ function to manipulate a SQL-Database, when for instance the user clicks on a button.

So basically i need something like the following (jQuery-shorthand):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#button").click(function(){
        mycppfunction();
    });
};)
```

I already read in the documentation and this  [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15868366/qt-webkit-bridge-c-access-to-javascript)  about the problem and the method `addToJavascriptWindowObject()`. However since I do not have a `QWebView` or `QWebFrame`, how i can actually achieve the same functionality, or rebuild the app to work as described.

Comment: The `Html5ApplicationViewer` class should contain the `QWebFrame` or similar, did you have a look at this class already?

Comment: I can't seem to find any documentation on it :(

Comment: how about looking at its header file?

Comment: since you found the relevant code according [to your follow up question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30177675/qt-expose-any-c-object-to-javascript), you might want to post an answer here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you would want to add, in order to make this work is the following

```
QWebFrame *frame = viewer.webView()->page()->mainFrame();
QString objJavascriptName = "myObj";
frame->addToJavaScriptWindowObject(objJavascriptName, &obj);
```

Add this after `Html5ApplicationViewer viewer;`